# applescript quit application by process id

Tags: applescript, exit, pid

Is it possible to quit an application in Applescript using process id(unix id in AS)? I have multiple instances of same application running and need to close one specific instance.
Something like:
tell application App (whose process unix id is 14241) to quit

Answer (score 1):

You can use the shell, for example:

**do shell script "kill 14241"**

Comment: Unfortunately, I wanted to avoid using shell commands because they kill the application ungracefully. Applescript, on the other hand, permits clean exit, which is why I want to use it.

Comment: In the end, used your solution with minor changes: do shell script "kill -SIGTERM 14241"